# Selecting similar elements from same list

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a file that contains information parsed from an Excel Sheet:

```
 class ProfileRecord
{
    public string ProfileCode { get; set; }
    public string DID { get; set; }
    public string AppName { get; set; }
    public string lvl1 { get; set; }
    public string lvl2 { get; set; }
    public string lvl3 { get; set; }
    public string lvl4 { get; set; }
}
```

In another Class, I send a list of these records for analysis. One thing I want to do is make a var that finds all of the matching ProfileCodes. So, say part of the excel sheet is :

```
Name     Profile Code
Billy    134
Sally    156
Mary     134
Jimmy    134
Tom      189
```

Then i would have something (I really dont know):

```
var sameProfile = from a in profileList
                  where ( //some code to group all similar profile codes)
                  select new
                  {
                    name = a.Name
                  };
```

If i were to print:

```
foreach(var p in sameProfile)
 {
    Console.WriteLine(p.name);
    Console.WriteLine("\n");
  }
```

I want to have:

```
Billy
Mary
Jimmy

Sally

Tom
```

Printed. I am unsure of how to find all simialr elements and group them using LINQ. Suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: It looks like a group by will do it.  check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325278/group-by-in-linq

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Enumerable.GroupBy`:

```
var profileCodeGroups = profileList
    .GroupBy(pr => pr.ProfileCode)
    .OrderBy(g => g.Key);

foreach(var grp in profileCodeGroups)
{
    foreach(var pr in grp)
        Console.WriteLine(pr.Name);
    Console.WriteLine("");
}
```

Comment: Awwww yeah. This is beatiful. I forgot about GroupBy. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the [`GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby.aspx) method:

```
var results = profileList.GroupBy(a => a.ProfileCode)
                         .Select(g => g.Select(a => a.Name));
```

Or in query syntax:

```
var results = 
    from a in profileList
    group a by a.ProfileCode into g
    select g.Select(a => a.Name);
```